# Javascript, fadeout non selection div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following were my html:

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
                                <select class=" form-control" title="Dropdown" id="country-change">
                                    <option value="all">All Countries</option>
                                    <option value="US">US</option>
                                    <option value="UK">UK</option> 
                                    <option value="USSR">USSR</option> 
                                </select>

                            </div>

<div class="col-md-12 country-<%=product.country%>">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <a href="<%= edit_product_path product %>" class="thumbnail">
                                                <% if product.product_overview_url.present? %>
                                                    <img src="<%= product.product_overview_url %>" alt="...">
                                                <% else %>
                                                    <img src="<%= asset_url('placehold_200_200.png') %>" alt="...">
                                                <% end %>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h5><%= product.name %>, for traveller in <%= product.city %></h5>
                                            <a href="/products/<%= product.id %>/edit"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Manage Listing and Price</a>
                                            <br>
                                            <a href="/products/<%= product.slug %>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i> Preview Listing</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-3">

                                            <select class=" form-control <%= product.status %> product-status" title="Dropdown" id="status-change" product-id="<%= product.id %>">
                                                <option value="enable" <%= 'selected' if product.status == 'enable' %>>Listed</option>
                                                <option value="disable" <%= 'selected' if product.status == 'disable' %>>Unlisted</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

The country in which the `div` belongs represented by `country-<%= product.country%>`, in which I will get results like:

```
<div class="col-md-12 country-UK">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country-US">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country-US">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country-USSR">...</div>
```

When a selection of which country need to be displayed is selected, how can I hide the non selected one?

```
$('#country-change').on('change', function(){
            var listed_country = $(this).val();
            $('.country-'+listed_country).fadeOut('slow');
        })
```

The above code hide the selected one. How can I can display the selected one and hide all the non selected? Thanks

Comment: `$('.country-'+listed_country).siblings().fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional class to all the div

```
<div class="col-md-12 country country-UK">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country country-US">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country country-US">...</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country country-USSR">...</div>
```

then hide all the country div elements other than the selected one

```
$('#country-change').on('change', function(){
    var listed_country = $(this).val();
    var $c = $('.country-'+listed_country).fadeIn('slow');
    $('div.country').not($c).fadeOut('slow');
})
```

```js
$('#country-change').on('change', function() {
  var listed_country = $(this).val();
  if (listed_country == 'All') {
    $('div.country').stop(true).fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    var $c = $('.country-' + listed_country).stop(true).fadeIn('slow');
    $('div.country').not($c).stop(true).fadeOut('slow');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country-change">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>UK</option>
  <option>US</option>
  <option>FR</option>
  <option>USSR</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-12 country country-UK">UK</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country country-US">US</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country country-FR">FR</div>
<div class="col-md-12 country country-USSR">USSR</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I jsut tried your code, but nothing happen. When I select USSR, the rest of div is not disappearing from the list.

Comment: @d3bug3r see the demo in the snippet

Comment: Ok, but how about for `all` cases? How to shows back all the countries?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the siblings of target element and only show current element:

```
$('#country-change').on('change', function(){
        var listed_country = $(this).val();
        var targetdiv = $('.country-'+listed_country);
        targetdiv.stop().fadeIn('slow');
        targetdiv.siblings().stop().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Got issues, once I select USSR, it works fine... But when I select back US, for a brief period it shows me US, then it gone!